# How could I input data to other worksheet in the Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

First of all, I'd like to input data to "test" worksheet, but I don't know how to write this code.

Second, I know there's different Shareable sheet link(**.../edit#gid=267921143**) each worksheet. However, I use Sheet.Best to convert into a API link.

It's suitable for a main page(forhere worksheet, link:**.../edit#gid=0**) of the Sheet below the code, and can work. That's why I want to use it to turn into other worksheet.

Tool: Dialogflow integrate with the Sheet(SheetDB & Sheet.Best)

Could someone give me a favor? Thanks a lot~

```
 function saveData(agent){
    const{
      name, age, email, phone, gender
    } = agent.parameters;
    const data3 = [{
      Name:name,
      Age:age,
      Email:email,
      Phone:phone,
      Gender:gender
    }];
    axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/...API...', data3);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5zL4.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with axios, but those links show you how to append values to a sheet with jNode according to the Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append As for exporting sheets

Answer (score 0):

Have already done.

Link: https://sheet.best/docs/working-with-tabs

```
Fix: axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/...API.../tabs/tablename, data3');
```